# InvalidCastException HttpWebRequest c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, background-agent

I have a problem: app throws InvalidCastException when I creating HttpWebRequest  in BackgroundAgent.
This code works in App foreground tasks, but doesn't works in BackgroundAgent:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(//InvalidCastException 
              new Uri(url));
          request.BeginGetResponse(r => {
            HttpWebRequest httprequest = (HttpWebRequest)r.AsyncState;
            try {
```

Full code: http://pastebin.com/zyCHBQuP

Comment: Does your url start with http or https?

Comment: Yeah, what he said. What's the value of `url`?

Comment: `https://api.vkontakte.ru/method/messages.get?count=" + 10 + "&preview_length=26&filters=1&access_token=" + ((App)App.Current).access_token`

Comment: what is the type returned from Create?

Comment: I would suggest that you break that statement up into three lines: `var myuri = new Uri(url);`, `var req = WebRequest.Create(myUri);` and `var request = (HttpWebRequest)req;`. That'll probably give you a better idea where the error actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type returned is dependent on the Uri passed into the Create method. You will get some descendant of WebRequest. You must be sure the Uri you pass is of the type that will return an HttpWebRequest if you are going to make that cast, or you will need to test the type returned from Create prior to casting or use the `as HttpWebRequest`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0aa3d588.aspx (for .net)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0aa3d588%28v=VS.95%29.aspx (for silverlight)